# Distribution of unbiased estimator given the sufficient statistic

Tags: estimators, sufficient-statistics

Let **T** be a sufficient statistic for parameter **a**, and **W** be an unbiased estimator of **a**, then will the distribution of **W|T** always be independent of parameter **a?**

I understand that **T** being sufficient for parameter **a**, the conditional distribution of sample, given **T** will be independent of parameter **a**, but will this be true for **W** also? (Where **W** is a function of sample observations only).

Comment: Hi @Kcd, can you add clarity around the statement, "...that T being sufficient, the distribution of sample given T will be independent of parameter"?

Comment: Hello @GeoffreyJohnson, does the edit make the question clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia states:

> A Rao–Blackwell estimator δ1(X) of an unobservable quantity θ is the
> conditional expected value E(δ(X) | T(X)) of some estimator δ(X) given
> a sufficient statistic T(X). Call δ(X) the "original estimator" and
> δ1(X) the "improved estimator". It is important that the improved
> estimator be observable, i.e. that it does not depend on θ. Generally,
> the conditional expected value of one function of these data given
> another function of these data does depend on θ, but the very
> definition of sufficiency given above entails that this one does not.

Wikipedia uses $\delta(X)$ instead of $W$.  I believe the last sentence provides the answer you are looking for.  Let me know if this does not address your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the following sentence  'but the very definition of sufficiency given above entails that this one does not.' ? Because, sufficiency just says conditional distribution of sample given the sufficient statistic is independent of parameter, from this, how can we conclude that the conditional distribution of a sample statistic (say W) given the sufficient statistic T will be independent of parameter?

Comment: The sentence just before says it is important that the improved estimator be observable.  In this way it will not be dependent on $\theta$.  Does this address your question?  I think this is to say that, we can conclude that the conditional distribution of a sample statistic given the sufficient statistic will be independent of the parameter if it is observable.  If it is a function of $\theta$ we will never be able to observe it.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!